# Formdata multiple files upload not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project. I'm trying to upload multiple images for that purpose. I'm running a for-loop, but the problem is that `FormData` isn't working, and it's empty.

**Form**

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addimgform" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 animated fadeIn">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form_images" id="images"
                   multiple name="images[]" type="file">
            <button class="save_imgs_btn btn-success" type="submit">
                Upload
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery/Ajax Function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.save_imgs_btn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var attachments = document.getElementById('images');
        var data_form = new FormData();
        for (i = 0; i < attachments.files.length; i++) {
            data_form.append('images', attachments.files[i]);
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "{{ route('update_media',['id'=>$data->id]) }}",
            data: data_form,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("working");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `type: 'get'` - maybe `post`?

Comment: try addding `[]` in as `data_form.append('images[]', attachments.files[i]);`

Comment: i have tried this data_form.append('images[]', attachments.files[i]); but still formdata is empty